# Debuging xamarin app using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I'am new in Xamarin. I want create new app using Xamarin in VS 2017. My steps:
    1) Install VS 2017 - community (Choose Item "Mobile development with .NET")
    2) File > New > Project
    3) Visual C#
    4) Android > Blank App (Android)

```
After thet I configuration AVD.

1) Tools > Android > Android Emulator Manager
2) Create
3) I set name "myAndroid"
4) Device = Nexus 6
5) Target = Android 7.1.1
6) CPU/ABI = Google APIs ARM (arm64 -vBa)
7) Skin = No skin
8) I check Use Host GPU
```

After configuration AVD I opened my Main.axml, and insert button. When i start debuging I see this message.

[image]

I click Ok  and waiting 5 minuts and see this. 
[image]

I want start my project not this. Please helpe me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the android emulators run incredibly slow when not using hardware acceleration. For some reason this does not come with visual studio. It's quick and easy to obtain this hardware acceleration. Google HAXM and download the installer. And as simple as that, the emulators will run fast enough that you can actually work on your project. However, you need to use the 86x bit versions of the emulators that came with visual studio for HAXM to work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But I have another problems. My procesor on the lap top does't suport HAXM, when I use x86 I have  error.

Comment: Did you try to install HAXM? It just failed to install? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

As @Launch9 suggested - always use x86 emulators to debug. You can download x86 image from Android SDK manager.
You can also use android virtual machines on Genymotion, since it can emulate different environmental conditions like connection quality, accelerometer and e.t.c. Last time I've checked they had free options for individuals.
Main advice - always try your code on real devices.